# MySql Where: get which criteria are not met against a record

Tags: mysql, sql, database, debugging

is there any way to get a list of reasons when a record in table is not selected from the query?
For example, I have this
`select * from products where color=blue and price=200`
and the record with id=5 is not included in the results. How can I print which criteria is false and the record with id=5 is not selected?

Comment: What do you mean "print which criteria is false" What are you expecting to see in your results? What if there's a million rows that don't match your filter?

Comment: the question is how to get the criteria which are false for a specific, targeted row. The answer I accepted is a nice workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually just copy the where criteria into the select columns, and select the particular id that wasn't returned, like:

```
select color=blue, price=200
from products
where id=5
```